# continue statement inside for loop and if condition

Tags: c++, c, continue

I have following code snippet and the output i am getting is 4. Please explain me if it takes i=2 or 0. I am confused. And How output was 4?

```
int main() {  
   int i=2;
   for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
      i=i%3;
      if(i==2) {
          i++;
          continue; }
      else
          ++i;  
   }
   printf("%d",i); 
}
```

Comment: Never write such code for anything but educational purpose!

Comment: What do you mean? You declare your int i and assign it value 2, then on the next line you assign 0 to it (the initialization part of the for-loop). How you get 4 as output is beyond me though, I get 2.

Comment: If you're getting 4 then you should change your compiler.

Comment: updating the for loop index (i) inside the loop in addition to the i++ in the for statement is a sure way to non-working code

Comment: i am using GCC 4.4.5 and its giving o/p as 4 only.

Answer (score 6):

The loop starts with  `i = 0`. Both the `if` and the `else` to exactly the same thing. Increment `i` and continue.
If you use a bit of logic, the whole block can be reduced to `i++` (`i = i % 3` has no effect since `i < 2`).

It's not possible to get `4` with the code you posted.

Comment: when i executed this code in gcc, i am getting o/p as 4 only. you can check.

Comment: @BabannaDuggani: in `gcc (GCC) 4.6.1 20110819 (prerelease)` the output is 2. IMO this is PEBKAC at best

Comment: friends, i am really sorry, in for loop it was i<3 and by mistake i wrote i<2 in the forum. I got it. thanks. Sorry for incovinience.

Answer (score 0):

The output cannot be `4` for the program you posted, because by the time the loop breaks, the value of `i` would be `2`, not `4` and the loop will run exactly *once*.

Also, your code never enters the `if` block, because the condition is `i==2` which can never be true inside the `for` loop, as by that time the loop would be exited.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```
int main() {  
   int i=2;
   for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
      i++;
   }
   printf("%d",i); 
}
```

Comment: when i executed this code in gcc, i am getting o/p as 4 only. you can check

Comment: @BabannaDuggani: You re-check your program. Compare this program which you're posted, and the one which you run on your pc. See if they're exactly same!

Comment: friends, i am really sorry, in for loop it was i<3 and by mistake i wrote i<2 in the forum. I got it. thanks. Sorry for incovinience.